# How do i address no.8&9 reasons for scheghen visa denial

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, finland

I would like to re-apply for a Schengen visa after my application was rejected two weeks ago. It should be noted I am employed on contract which is renewable every year. I am not married and have no kids, neither do I have property. I am an administrative assistant earning $207.45 per month. Personal savings amounting to $3,268.85 and $1,595.35 on my salary account. I submitted these documents for my first Schengen application but I was denied. I must say I messed up during the phone interview;

- Days to be spent in Finland: I said 10 working days but my application said 14 days
- Purpose of visit: I said wanted to go to the Santa clause village, visit my friend and other places. But my main purpose was to visit a friend I had not seen in 10 years.
- They asked me how much I earn and whether it was before tax or after tax
- Why I wanted to visit this friend of mine after 10 years

I noticed when I was applying I did not put a cover letter, payslips and employment contract plus messing up the phone interview.

I received the refusal letter stating;

- Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.
- Information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and condition of the intended stay were not reliable.

I would like to reapply soon but how do I address these two reasons in order to get my visa application approved?
Plus how should I write my cover letter addressing these issues?

Documents submitted were:
employment letter, Application letter, Passport photos, Photos of me and my friend, bank statement(with $1,861),Travel insurance, travel literary, invitation letter from host, his copy of passport, permanent residence card, my national id, passport travel history, leave form.

Comment: Your monthly pay is about one sixth of the effective minimum wage in Finland. Your problem may well be that an immigration officer isn't going to believe that anyone would spend a significant fraction of their life savings on a two-week trip to visit somebody they've not seen in ten years.

Comment: Sounds like a letter from the friend to say they're paying for everything and you were super close throughout childhood etc... would be the necessary. But even then its tough

Comment: David so you suggest I do not re apply I should wait till my circumstances change...

Comment: How long then should I wait till this refusal is wiped out of the system...

Comment: Then I can apply for Schengen visa from another embassy say the France.

Comment: @josephineNamusoke, going to another Schengen country will not "wipe" your record.

Comment: Big alarm bells ringing that this isn't an honest visit with an attempt to game the system by going to another country....